# Accept non-standard css properties in PyCharm?

Tags: css, pycharm

I have the following rule

```
    .selectable { /* double click -> select (not text-selection) */
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

where every property (except `cursor`) shows with a red squiggly line in the PyCharm editor and the message "Unknown CSS property -webkit-touch-callout..".

I understand that `user-select` is non-standard, but is there a way to tell PyCharm that I've understood the warning and please stop nagging me about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable **Ignore vendor specific CSS properties** option:

[image: Ignore vendor specific CSS properties]